# page navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm very new to phonegap and have had to pick up someone else's code. I am having an issue with page navigation. I have an onClick event on a list item and depending on a boolean, I want to navigate to a specific page.

The two possible pages the user will move to are almost identical. There is only one div which is different containing a list view. Originally I had only one page and I loaded the html of the div dynamically with javascript but the css was not being applied to so I decided to create an additional page which was almost identical apart from the one div mentioned above.

My issue now is that whichever div(page) I create first in my index.html will work for navigation but the second one will not i.e.

if I define the divs in the following order:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page"></div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page"></div>
```

then navigating to page1 will work and navigating to page 2 will not. But if I switch the order in which I place the divs in the index.html page i.e.

```
<div id="page2" data-role="page"></div>

<div id="page1" data-role="page"></div>
```

then navigating to page 2 will work and navigating to page 1 will not.

Hope this made sense. Here is my code:

In the head tag I have the following function:

```
function SetMyAccountsBool(bool){
        MyAccountsBool=bool;

        if (CheckBool){
            alert('here');
            $.mobile.changePage("file:///Users/roseannecarroll/Documents/workspace2/GirtBank/assets/www/index.html#MyAccTrans4");
            //window.location = "file:///Users/roseannecarroll/Documents/workspace2/GirtBank/assets/www/index.html#MyAccTrans3";
            //$("#MyAccTrans3").trigger("pagecreate");

        }
        else{
            alert('here2');
            //$.mobile.changePage('#MyAccTrans');
$.mobile.changePage("file:///Users/roseannecarroll/Documents/workspace2/GirtBank/assets/www/index.html#MyAccTrans");

        }
    };
```

Then on a listview, I am calling the above function as an onClick event. It is entering the function, as I am getting the alert either 'here' or 'here2' depending on a boolean.

And finally here are the two almost identical divs I have:

```
<div id="MyAccTrans" div class="page" data-role="page" data-theme="a" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#TransferMoney" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-transition="slide"></a>

            <div class="centered">
                <img src="../images/log_out.png" alt="Log_Out" onclick='javascript:location.href="#loginScreen";' class="c1">
                <h3><div id="MyAccTrans_NAME"></div>Choose</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 10px;text-align:center">
            <div class="centered">
                <div class="centered" id="MyAccTrans_NUMBER"></div>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="bookbal"><b><div id="MyAccTrans_BOOK_BAL"></div></b>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="accountnum">

        </div>
        <div style="padding:10px">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Choose Existing Account To Transfer:
                </li>
                <div id="MyAccTrans_target_div" style="padding:10px">
               <ul id="MyAccTrans_ul" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a">
        <li id="0" data-theme="c"><a href="#makeTransfer" data-transition="slide" >
        Savings - 173</a><div ><a href="#MyAccTrans" data-transition="slide"> 
        </a></div></li></ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"  class="centered3" data-theme="a" >
            <a href="#" onClick="boolCheck();" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/homeGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#exchangeCalc" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/EuroGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#loanCalc" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/CalculatorGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#other" class="tabBAR" data-role="button" ><img src="../images/locationGrey50.png"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

AND

```
<div id="MyAccTrans4" div class="page" data-role="page" data-theme="a" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div class="centered">
                <img src="../images/log_out.png" alt="Log_Out" onclick='javascript:location.href="#loginScreen";' class="c1">
                <h3><div id="MyAccTrans_NAME"></div>Choose</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 10px;text-align:center">
            <div class="centered">
                <div class="centered" id="MyAccTrans_NUMBER4"></div>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="bookbal"><b><div id="MyAccTrans_BOOK_BAL4"></div></b>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="accountnum">
        </div>
        <div style="padding:10px">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Choose Existing Account To Transfer:
                </li>
                <div id="MyAccTrans_target_div4" style="padding:10px">

               <ul id="MyAccTrans_ul4" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a">
        <li id="0" data-theme="c"><a href="#makeTransfer" data-transition="slide" >
        Current - 004</a><div ><a href="#MyAccTrans" data-transition="slide"> 
        </a></div></li></ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"  class="centered3" data-theme="a" >
            <a href="#" onClick="boolCheck();" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/homeGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#exchangeCalc" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/EuroGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#loanCalc" class="tabBAR" data-role="button"><img src="../images/CalculatorGrey50.png"></a>
            <a href="#other" class="tabBAR" data-role="button" ><img src="../images/locationGrey50.png"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated